# SQL to UML diagram or graphic tool

Tags: sql, uml

I have a database and want to output a UML Diagram. Is there software that does this?

Ideally it will be UML, but a graphics representation of the database could work.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boxes and arrows are all you need, but I'd recommend that you try E/R tools.  They are similar to UML, but intended for relational databases.  A good one can import and export SQL, which you won't get from a UML tool.

If you use MySQL, the MySQL Workbench does a very nice job, indeed.

Comment: Do you have any link for "E/R Tools"?

Comment: Is MySQL Workbench not enough of a hint for you?  http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Erwin Data Modeler, Embarcadero's ER Studio, or Microsoft's Visio.  For a longer list visit this site http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect from [Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com) is a commercial UML modelling tool, with data(base) modelling facilities which include forward (to SQL) and reverse (from ODBC) schema engineering.

It supports most of the biggest databases, including Oracle, Sybase, MySQL, Access, SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Dali plugin of Eclipse. You just need a jdbc conncetor and can create java code from your database. From java code you then just reverse engineer the code into UML model in order to get class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliJ IDEA built-in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-diagrams.html) does perfect job and supports a load of DBMS types.

> **Generate a diagram for a database object**﻿
>
> In the Database tool window (**View | Tool Windows | Database**),
> right-click a database object and select **Diagrams | Show Visualization**.

[image: Generate a diagram for a database object]

The resulting ERD can then be exported in multiple formats:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

actually i found a software that do what you want it is called draw.io its main use is to create diagrams but if you went to arrange section then insert and chose advanced you will find SQL where you can put your SQL code and it will make it as diagram

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntelliJ DataGrip's inbuilt tools. In the Database tool window ( View | Tool Windows | Database), right-click a database object(that you want to visualize in diagram) and select Diagrams | Show Visualization and you got the diagram .