# SQL Query to ER-type diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, uml, entity-relationship

I'm getting started with SQL. So far, most of my experience is either with simple queries using C# (then performing operations on the data in C#), or designing [relatively] more complex queries with MS Access' design view.

I was recently assigned a task to review a relatively large query (hundreds of rows for a single Select), and there are minimal comments in the code. Also, I'm not familiar with the database being queried. Even though the syntax seems relatively simple, there are so many joins on top of joins that it's hard to wrap my head around.

Ideally, I'd like to have some graphical representation, similar to MS Access' design view. Note that my current position uses SSMS. I'm aware there are tools that can create SQL code from a UML diagram. I'm also aware that there are tools that can create a ER diagram from SQL code ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528118/sql-to-uml-diagram-or-graphic-tool)), which is closer to what I'm looking for. Are these ER tools my only option? As far as I can tell, the ER tools only show db relationships, and *not* specific queries with special types of joins or functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Management Studio (I use 2008) you can just right click on the diagrams drop down in the explorer and click Create New Diagram. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but this is how I make all of my ER diagrams for my database.

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio 2008. But I don't see any "diagrams drop down". Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: nsw sorry for my late reply but here is an image (I hope imgur is ok) of what I mean. It's after you select your database there is something that says 'Database Diagrams', right click that and then click 'New Diagram' and select the tables you want relationships for, assuming the relationships have already been made it will be automatic. http://i.imgur.com/ZOjavTV.png

Comment: When I attempt this, I get the error message "A member of the db_owner role must use the database diagramming functionality in order to setup the required database diagramming objects on the SQL Server." In any case, this does not seem to be related to the actual query I'm reviewing.

Comment: Do you want an er diagram of the actual query you're running or the tables? I'm confused now so this might be out of my knowledge.

Comment: The actual query I'm running. For example, something like this (from MS Access' design view): http://forums.techguy.org/attachments/145373d1233159585/designview.jpg

Answer (score 0):

No, It is impossible to do this by using standart tools like SQL Management Studio or others. 
Maybe there exist some specific tools for this. 
It is difficult and interesting task to generate joins diagram from SQL query (It is simple for "joins" but how does "union" and "where" clauses should be explained on diagram?)
And I think it doesnt simplify you task.

Comment: For example, this image shows multiple joins with "where" clauses (in the criteria field). http://forums.techguy.org/attachments/145373d1233159585/designview.jpg

But this is from MS Access.